# Unity sound when cube hit wall

Tags: audio, unity-game-engine

I have sound source and my question is how can I play that sound when my cube hit a wall?

I tried something like this, but it doesn't work.

```
usingUnityEngine;
usingSystem.Collections;

public class sound : MonoBehaviour {

voidOnTriggerEnter (Colliderother) 
{
if(other.gameObject.tag == "wall")
{

Audio.PlayOneShot(sound);

}

}
}
```

I hope that someone will answer me. It's too important for me. Last few days I searched the whole Internet, I did so many changes on my game, but nothing work :(

Kind regards

Comment: Preliminary questions: What is the format of your sound file? Have you used `Debug.Log` to check that the function is actually called?

Comment: Numid is correct.  Use a `debug.Log` to also check if `other.gameObject.tag == "wall"` is true.

Answer (score 1):

```
usingUnityEngine;
usingSystem.Collections;

public class sound : MonoBehaviour {

public AudioSource soundEffect;

voidOnTriggerEnter (Collider other) 
{
   if(other.gameObject.tag == "wall")
   {
      soundEffect.Play ();
   }
}
}
```

Assign audio source to script in inspector and assign script to cube.

Comment: code is fine, but I can't add my .mp3 sound to the script.

Comment: Can you explain what problem occur?

Comment: I cannot put file on box (" Sound effect: None (Audio Source) " ). I try put my .mp3 sound on this line, but it doesn't accept.